# Natural merge sort - follow-up

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, mergesort, c++14

The previous iteration at [Natural merge sort](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/86507/natural-merge-sort)

Now my code relies on C++14 and looks like:

**natural_merge_sort.h**:

```
#ifndef NATURAL_MERGE_SORT_H
#define NATURAL_MERGE_SORT_H

#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

/*******************************************************************************
* Implements a simple, array-based queue of integers. All three operations run *
* in constant time. This queue, however, does not check for under-/overflow of *
* underlying buffer because of performance considerations.                     *
*******************************************************************************/
class UnsafeIntQueue {
private:
    const size_t MINIMUM_CAPACITY = 256;

    size_t m_head;
    size_t m_tail;
    size_t m_size;
    size_t m_mask;
    size_t* m_buffer;

    /***************************************************************************
    * Makes sure a capacity is at least 'MINIMUM_CAPACITY' and is a power of   *
    * two.                                                                     *
    ***************************************************************************/
    size_t fixCapacity(size_t capacity)
    {
        capacity = std::max(capacity, MINIMUM_CAPACITY);
        size_t s = 1;

        while (s < capacity)
        {
            s <<= 1;
        }

        return s;
    }

public:

    /***************************************************************************
    * Constructs a new integer queue, which can accommodate 'capacit' amount   *
    * integers.                                                                *
    ***************************************************************************/
    UnsafeIntQueue(size_t capacity) :
    m_head{0},
    m_tail{0},
    m_size{0}
    {
        capacity = fixCapacity(capacity);
        m_mask = capacity - 1;
        m_buffer = new size_t[capacity];
    }

    /***************************************************************************
    * Destroys this queue, which releases the underlying buffer.               *
    ***************************************************************************/
    ~UnsafeIntQueue()
    {
        delete[] m_buffer;
    }

    /***************************************************************************
    * Appends the input integer to the tail of this queue.                     *
    ***************************************************************************/
    inline void enqueue(const size_t element)
    {
        m_buffer[m_tail & m_mask] = element;
        m_tail = (m_tail + 1) & m_mask;
        m_size++;
    }

    /***************************************************************************
    * Removes and returns the integer at the head of this queue.               *
    ***************************************************************************/
    inline size_t dequeue()
    {
        const size_t ret = m_buffer[m_head];
        m_head = (m_head + 1) & m_mask;
        m_size--;
        return ret;
    }

    /***************************************************************************
    * Returns the amount of integers in this queue.                            *
    ***************************************************************************/
    inline size_t size() const
    {
        return m_size;
    }
};

/*******************************************************************************
* Scans the range [first, lst) and returns the queue containing sizes of each  *
* run in the order they appear while scanning from left to right.              *
*******************************************************************************/
template<class RandomIt, class Cmp>
std::unique_ptr<UnsafeIntQueue> build_run_size_queue(RandomIt first,
                                                     RandomIt lst,
                                                     Cmp cmp)
{
    const size_t length = std::distance(first, lst);
    UnsafeIntQueue* p_q = new UnsafeIntQueue(length / 2 + 1);

    RandomIt head;
    RandomIt left = first;
    RandomIt right = left + 1;

    const RandomIt last = lst - 1;

    while (left < last)
    {
        head = left;

        if (cmp(*right++, *left++))
        {
            // Reading a strictly descending run.
            while (left < last && cmp(*right, *left))
            {
                ++left;
                ++right;
            }

            p_q->enqueue(right - head);
            std::reverse(head, right);
        }
        else
        {
            // Reading a ascending run.
            while (left < last && !cmp(*right, *left))
            {
                ++left;
                ++right;
            }

            p_q->enqueue(left - head + 1);
        }

        ++left;
        ++right;
    }

    if (left == last)
    {
        // Handle the case of an orphan element at the end of the range.
        p_q->enqueue(1);
    }

    return std::unique_ptr<UnsafeIntQueue>(p_q);
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Returns the amount of leading zeros in 'num'.                                *
*******************************************************************************/
size_t leading_zeros(const size_t num)
{
    size_t count = 0;

    for (size_t t = (size_t) 1 << (8 * sizeof(t) - 1); t; t >>= 1, ++count)
    {
        if ((t & num))
        {
            return count;
        }
    }

    return count;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Returns the amount of merge passes needed to sort a range with 'run_amount'  *
* runs.                                                                        *
*******************************************************************************/
size_t get_pass_amount(size_t run_amount)
{
    return 8 * sizeof(run_amount) - leading_zeros(run_amount - 1);
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Implements the natural merge sort, which sacrifices one pass over the input  *
* range in order to establish an implicit queue of runs. A run is the longest  *
* consecutive subsequence, in which all elements are ascending or strictly     *
* descending. Every descending run is reversed to ascending run. We cannot     *
* consider non-strictly descending runs, since that would sacrifice the stabi- *
* lity of the algorithm. After the run queue is establish, the algorithm re-   *
* moves two runs from the head of the queue, merges them into one run, which   *
* is then appended to the tail of the run queue. Merging continues until the   *
* queue contains only one run, which denotes that the entire input range is    *
* sorted.                                                                      *
*                                                                              *
* The best-case complexity is O(N), the average and worst-case complexity is   *
* O(N log N). Space complexity is O(N).                                        *
*******************************************************************************/
template<class RandomIt, class Cmp>
void natural_merge_sort(RandomIt first, RandomIt last, Cmp cmp)
{
    const size_t length = std::distance(first, last);

    if (length < 2)
    {
        // Trivially sorted.
        return;
    }

    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<RandomIt>::value_type value_type;

    // Scan the runs.
    std::unique_ptr<UnsafeIntQueue> p_queue = build_run_size_queue(first, last, cmp);

    // Request a buffer.
    RandomIt buffer = new value_type[length];

    // Count the amount of merge passes over the array required to bring order.
    const size_t merge_passes = get_pass_amount(p_queue->size());

    RandomIt source;
    RandomIt target;

    // Make sure that after the last merge pass, all data ends up in the input
    // container.
    if ((merge_passes & 1) == 1)
    {
        source = buffer;
        target = first;
        std::copy(first, last, buffer);
    }
    else
    {
        source = first;
        target = buffer;
    }

    size_t runs_left = p_queue->size();
    size_t offset = 0;

    // While there is runs to merge, do...
    while (p_queue->size() > 1)
    {
        // Remove two runs from the head of the run queue.
        size_t left_run_length = p_queue->dequeue();
        size_t right_run_length = p_queue->dequeue();

        std::merge(source + offset,
                   source + offset + left_run_length,
                   source + offset + left_run_length,
                   source + offset + left_run_length + right_run_length,
                   target + offset,
                   cmp);

        // Append the merged run to the tail of the queue.
        p_queue->enqueue(left_run_length + right_run_length);
        runs_left -= 2;
        offset += left_run_length + right_run_length;

        // The current pass over the array is almost complete.
        switch (runs_left)
        {
            case 1:
            {
                const size_t single_length = p_queue->dequeue();

                std::copy(source + offset,
                          source + offset + single_length,
                          target + offset);

                p_queue->enqueue(single_length);
            }

            // FALL THROUGH!

            case 0:
            {
                runs_left = p_queue->size();
                offset = 0;
                RandomIt tmp = source;
                source = target;
                target = tmp;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    delete[] buffer;
}

#endif
```

**main.cpp**:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

#include "natural_merge_sort.h"

/*******************************************************************************
* Creates a random integer array of length 'length', minimum integer           *
* 'minimum', maximum integer 'maximum', using seed 'seed'.                     *
*******************************************************************************/
static int* get_random_int_array(const size_t length,
                                 const int minimum,
                                 const int maximum,
                                 const unsigned int seed)
{
    std::default_random_engine generator(seed);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(minimum, maximum);

    int* array = new int[length];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        array[i] = distribution(generator);
    }

    return array;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Create an array of pointers to integers.                                     *
*******************************************************************************/
static int** get_random_int_pointer_array(const size_t length,
                                          const int minimum,
                                          const int maximum,
                                          const unsigned seed)
{
    std::default_random_engine generator(seed);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(minimum, maximum);

    int** array = new int*[length];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        array[i] = new int(distribution(generator));
    }

    return array;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Returns a strongly presorted array of integers.                              *
*******************************************************************************/
static int* get_presorted_int_array(const size_t length)
{
    int* array = new int[length];
    int num = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < length / 2; ++i)
    {
        array[i] = num++;
    }

    for (size_t i = length / 2; i < length; ++i)
    {
        array[i] = num--;
    }

    return array;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Returns the milliseconds since the Unix epoch.                               *
*******************************************************************************/
static unsigned long long get_milliseconds()
{
    return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(
           std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Profiles the 'std::stable_sort' agains the range ['begin', 'end') using the  *
* comparator 'cmp'.                                                            *
*******************************************************************************/
template<class T, class Cmp>
static void profile_stable_sort(T begin, T end, Cmp cmp)
{
    unsigned long long ta = get_milliseconds();
    std::stable_sort(begin, end, cmp);
    unsigned long long tb = get_milliseconds();

    std::cout << "std::stable_sort in "
              << (tb - ta)
              << " milliseconds. "
              << "Sorted: "
              << std::is_sorted(begin, end, cmp)
              << std::endl;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Profiles the 'natural_merge_sort' agains the range ['begin', 'end') using    *
* the comparator 'cmp'.                                                        *
*******************************************************************************/
template<class T, class Cmp>
void profile_natural_merge_sort(T begin, T end, Cmp cmp)
{
    unsigned long long ta = get_milliseconds();
    natural_merge_sort(begin, end, cmp);
    unsigned long long tb = get_milliseconds();

    std::cout << "natural_merge_sort in "
              << (tb - ta)
              << " milliseconds. "
              << "Sorted: "
              << std::is_sorted(begin, end, cmp)
              << std::endl;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Profiles the sorting algorithms on a random integer array.                   *
*******************************************************************************/
static void profile_on_random_array(const size_t sz,
                                    const int minimum,
                                    const int maximum,
                                    const unsigned seed)
{
    int* array1 = get_random_int_array(sz, minimum, maximum, seed);
    int* array2 = new int[sz];
    std::copy(array1, array1 + sz, array2);

    std::cout << "--- PROFILING ON RANDOM ARRAY OF LENGTH "
              << sz
              << " ---"
              << std::endl;

    profile_stable_sort(array1, 
                        array1 + sz, 
                        std::less<>());

    profile_natural_merge_sort(array2, 
                               array2 + sz, 
                               std::less<>());

    std::cout << "Same contents: "
              << std::equal(array1, array1 + sz, array2, array2 + sz)
              << std::endl
              << std::endl;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Profiles the sorting algorithms on an array of pointers to random integers.  *
*******************************************************************************/
static void profile_on_integer_pointer_array(const size_t sz,
                                             const int minimum,
                                             const int maximum,
                                             const unsigned seed)
{
    std::cout << "--- PROFILING ON RANDOM POINTER ARRAY OF LENGTH "
              << sz
              << " ---"
              << std::endl;

    int** array1 = get_random_int_pointer_array(sz,
                                                minimum,
                                                maximum,
                                                seed);
    int** array2 = new int*[sz];
    std::copy(array1, array1 + sz, array2);

    auto lambda = [](int* a, int* b){
        return *a < *b;
    };

    profile_stable_sort(array1, 
                        array1 + sz, 
                        lambda);

    profile_natural_merge_sort(array2, 
                               array2 + sz, 
                               lambda);

    std::cout << "Same contents: "
              << std::equal(array1, array1 + sz, array2, array2 + sz)
              << std::endl
              << std::endl;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Profiles the sorting algorithms on a presorted array.                        *
*******************************************************************************/
static void profile_on_presorted_array(const size_t sz)
{
    std::cout << "--- PROFILING ON PRESORTED ARRAY OF LENGTH "
              << sz
              << " ---"
              << std::endl;

    int* array1 = get_presorted_int_array(sz);
    int* array2 = new int[sz];
    std::copy(array1, array1 + sz, array2);

    profile_stable_sort(array1, 
                        array1 + sz, 
                        std::less<>());

    profile_natural_merge_sort(array2, 
                               array2 + sz, 
                               std::less<>());

    std::cout << "Same contents: "
              << std::equal(array1, array1 + sz, array2, array2 + sz)
              << std::endl
              << std::endl;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* The entry point to a demo program.                                           *
*******************************************************************************/
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    unsigned long long seed = get_milliseconds();

    std::cout << "Seed: "
              << seed
              << std::endl
              << std::endl;

    const size_t length = 5000000;
    const int min_int = -10000;
    const int max_int = 30000;

    std::cout << std::boolalpha;

    profile_on_random_array(length, min_int, max_int, seed);
    profile_on_integer_pointer_array(length, min_int, max_int, seed);
    profile_on_presorted_array(length);

    return 0;
}
```

I have done the following:

- `is_sorted` changed to `std::is_sorted` (no need to reinvent the wheel)
- `are_equal` changed to `std::equal`
- `compare_int` changed to `std::less<int>`
- `compare_dereference` changed to a lambda
- `merge` changed to `std::merge`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are still things you could improve to the implementation of the algorithm:

- You are missing a `#include <memory>` for `std::unique_ptr`. It may be included by another standard library header, but it's not guaranteed. In fact, it triggered a compilation error with g++.
- You could make `natural_merge_sort` take a default comparator such as `std::less<>` so that it can be called without an explicit comparator, like many of the standard library's algorithms:

  ```
  template<class RandomIt, class Cmp=std::less<>>
  void natural_merge_sort(RandomIt first, RandomIt last, Cmp cmp=Cmp{})
  ```
- Apparently, you failed to take into account [@Hurkyl's comments](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/86540/15094) in this follow-up. They are still worth it: don't manage memory manually if you don't have to. Using `std::unique_ptr<size_t[]>` instead of `size_t*` is still an excellent idea:

  ```
  std::unique_ptr<size_t[]> m_buffer;
  ```

  With such a member, you can totally get rid of `UnsafeIntQueue`'s destructor and it will still make sure that the memory is always properly deallocated when an operation throws. Moreover, it will make your code follow the [Rule of Zero](https://rmf.io/cxx11/rule-of-zero/) which is more and more recommended by guidelines.
- When I read `RandomIt`, I thought that your algorithm would work out-of-the-box for any random-access iterator type. Unfortunately, it does not, partly because of the following line:

  ```
  RandomIt buffer = new value_type[length];
  ```

  You should either make it clear in the documentation that your algorithm works only with pointers, or change your algorithm so that it works with any random-access iterator type. The latter requires significant work, so I won't propose any modification here.
- When dealing with iterators, don't hesitate to use [`std::next`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next) and [`std::prev`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/prev) instead of writing `+1` and `-1`. They make it obvious that the addition/subtraction is performed on an iterator and not on a size (while the meaning of `+1` and `-1` is not always obvious when reading an algorithm).

  ```
  RandomIt head;
  RandomIt left = first;
  RandomIt right = std::next(left);

  const RandomIt last = std::prev(lst);
  ```

  Another benefit is that these functions accept bidirectional iterators. Changing the manual additions and subtractions by these functions sometimes make simple algorithms work with bidirectional iterators instead of just random-access iterators.
- For the exact same reasons, using [`std::distance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) is good. Upon reading `p_q->enqueue(right - head);`, I actually had to look up the declarations of `right` and `left` to check whether they represented sizes or iterators. Using `std::distance` would have made it clear that they were iterators.
- When you see things like `8 * sizeof(t)` in a function that performs bit tricks, it almost always means that `8` is a drop-in replacement for [`CHAR_BIT`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/climits). That also means that what you actually want is [`std::numeric_limits<size_t>::digits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/digits) which is equivalent to `CHAR_BIT * sizeof(size_t)` and helps to write generic code.
- You can use `constexpr` to make it obvious that some constants are actually compile-time constants. Also, if a constant is part of the class and does not depend on the state of the class, make it `static` too:

  ```
  static constexpr std::size_t MINIMUM_CAPACITY = 256;
  ```

  Note that I also explicitly wrote a fully qualified `std::size_t`: some implementations of the standard library simply don't import the names from the standard C library in the global namespace, so prefixing every component of the standard library with `std::` is good practice.
- Instead of the traditional `typedef` inherited from C, don't hesitate to use the new shiny [type alias](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) offered by C++11. It looks more like a regular assignment (it makes it easier to reason about it) and can even be templated:

  ```
  using value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<RandomIt>::value_type;
  ```