# Parallel natural merge sort

Tags: c++, sorting, concurrency, mergesort, c++14

Continuing working on [Natural merge sort](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/86507/natural-merge-sort), I have parallelized it. Requires \$\Theta(N)\$ space and runs in $$\Omega(N + \frac{N}{P}) \cap \mathcal{O}(N + \frac{N}{P}\log_2\frac{N}{P})$$ time, where \$P\$ is the amount of cores available.

**parallel_natural_merge_sort.h**:

```
#ifndef NATURAL_MERGE_SORT_H
#define NATURAL_MERGE_SORT_H

#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <thread>

/*******************************************************************************
* Implements a simple, array-based queue of integers. All three operations run *
* in constant time. This queue, however, does not check for under-/overflow of *
* underlying buffer because of performance considerations.                     *
*******************************************************************************/
class UnsafeIntQueue {
private:
    const size_t MINIMUM_CAPACITY = 256;

    size_t m_head;
    size_t m_tail;
    size_t m_size;
    size_t m_mask;
    size_t* m_buffer;

    /***************************************************************************
    * Makes sure a capacity is at least 'MINIMUM_CAPACITY' and is a power of   *
    * two.                                                                     *
    ***************************************************************************/
    size_t fixCapacity(size_t capacity)
    {
        capacity = std::max(capacity, MINIMUM_CAPACITY);
        size_t s = 1;

        while (s < capacity)
        {
            s <<= 1;
        }

        return s;
    }

public:

    /***************************************************************************
    * Constructs a new integer queue, which can accommodate 'capacit' amount   *
    * integers.                                                                *
    ***************************************************************************/
    UnsafeIntQueue(size_t capacity) :
    m_head{0},
    m_tail{0},
    m_size{0}
    {
        capacity = fixCapacity(capacity);
        m_mask = capacity - 1;
        m_buffer = new size_t[capacity];
    }

    /***************************************************************************
    * Destroys this queue, which releases the underlying buffer.               *
    ***************************************************************************/
    ~UnsafeIntQueue()
    {
        delete[] m_buffer;
    }

    /***************************************************************************
    * Appends the input integer to the tail of this queue.                     *
    ***************************************************************************/
    inline void enqueue(const size_t element)
    {
        m_buffer[m_tail & m_mask] = element;
        m_tail = (m_tail + 1) & m_mask;
        m_size++;
    }

    /***************************************************************************
    * Removes and returns the integer at the head of this queue.               *
    ***************************************************************************/
    inline size_t dequeue()
    {
        const size_t ret = m_buffer[m_head];
        m_head = (m_head + 1) & m_mask;
        m_size--;
        return ret;
    }

    /***************************************************************************
    * Returns the amount of integers in this queue.                            *
    ***************************************************************************/
    inline size_t size() const
    {
        return m_size;
    }
};

/*******************************************************************************
* Scans the range [first, last) and returns the queue containing sizes of each *
* run in the order they appear while scanning from left to right.              *
*******************************************************************************/
template<class RandomIt, class Cmp>
std::unique_ptr<UnsafeIntQueue> build_run_size_queue(RandomIt first,
                                                     RandomIt last,
                                                     Cmp cmp)
{
    const size_t length = std::distance(first, last);
    UnsafeIntQueue* p_q = new UnsafeIntQueue(length / 2 + 1);

    RandomIt head;
    RandomIt left = first;
    RandomIt right = left + 1;

    const RandomIt lst = last - 1;

    while (left < lst)
    {
        head = left;

        if (cmp(*right++, *left++))
        {
            // Reading a strictly descending run.
            while (left < lst && cmp(*right, *left))
            {
                ++left;
                ++right;
            }

            p_q->enqueue(right - head);
            std::reverse(head, right);
        }
        else
        {
            // Reading a ascending run.
            while (left < lst && !cmp(*right, *left))
            {
                ++left;
                ++right;
            }

            p_q->enqueue(left - head + 1);
        }

        ++left;
        ++right;
    }

    if (left == lst)
    {
        // Handle the case of an orphan element at the end of the range.
        p_q->enqueue(1);
    }

    return std::unique_ptr<UnsafeIntQueue>(p_q);
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Returns the amount of leading zeros in 'num'.                                *
*******************************************************************************/
size_t leading_zeros(const size_t num)
{
    size_t count = 0;

    for (size_t t = (size_t) 1 << (8 * sizeof(t) - 1); t; t >>= 1, ++count)
    {
        if ((t & num))
        {
            return count;
        }
    }

    return count;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Returns the amount of merge passes needed to sort a range with 'run_amount'  *
* runs.                                                                        *
*******************************************************************************/
size_t get_pass_amount(size_t run_amount)
{
    return 8 * sizeof(run_amount) - leading_zeros(run_amount - 1);
}

/*******************************************************************************
* The actual implementation of natural merge sort.                             *
*******************************************************************************/
template<class RandomIt, class Cmp>
void natural_merge_sort_impl(RandomIt first, 
                             RandomIt last, 
                             RandomIt buffer,
                             Cmp cmp)
{
    const size_t length = std::distance(first, last);

    if (length < 2)
    {
        // Trivially sorted.
        return;
    }

    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<RandomIt>::value_type value_type;

    // Scan the runs.
    std::unique_ptr<UnsafeIntQueue> p_queue = build_run_size_queue(first, last, cmp);

    // Count the amount of merge passes over the array required to bring order.
    const size_t merge_passes = get_pass_amount(p_queue->size());

    RandomIt source;
    RandomIt target;

    // Make sure that after the last merge pass, all data ends up in the input
    // container.
    if ((merge_passes & 1) == 1)
    {
        source = buffer;
        target = first;
        std::copy(first, last, buffer);
    }
    else
    {
        source = first;
        target = buffer;
    }

    size_t runs_left = p_queue->size();
    size_t offset = 0;

    // While there is runs to merge, do...
    while (p_queue->size() > 1)
    {
        // Remove two runs from the head of the run queue.
        size_t left_run_length = p_queue->dequeue();
        size_t right_run_length = p_queue->dequeue();

        std::merge(source + offset,
                   source + offset + left_run_length,
                   source + offset + left_run_length,
                   source + offset + left_run_length + right_run_length,
                   target + offset,
                   cmp);

        // Append the merged run to the tail of the queue.
        p_queue->enqueue(left_run_length + right_run_length);
        runs_left -= 2;
        offset += left_run_length + right_run_length;

        // The current pass over the array is almost complete.
        switch (runs_left)
        {
            case 1:
            {
                const size_t single_length = p_queue->dequeue();

                std::copy(source + offset,
                          source + offset + single_length,
                          target + offset);

                p_queue->enqueue(single_length);
            }

            // FALL THROUGH!

            case 0:
            {
                runs_left = p_queue->size();
                offset = 0;
                RandomIt tmp = source;
                source = target;
                target = tmp;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Implements the natural merge sort, which sacrifices one pass over the input  *
* range in order to establish an implicit queue of runs. A run is the longest  *
* consecutive subsequence, in which all elements are ascending or strictly     *
* descending. Every descending run is reversed to ascending run. We cannot     *
* consider non-strictly descending runs, since that would sacrifice the stabi- *
* lity of the algorithm. After the run queue is establish, the algorithm re-   *
* moves two runs from the head of the queue, merges them into one run, which   *
* is then appended to the tail of the run queue. Merging continues until the   *
* queue contains only one run, which denotes that the entire input range is    *
* sorted.                                                                      *
*                                                                              *
* The best-case complexity is O(N), the average and worst-case complexity is   *
* O(N log N). Space complexity is O(N).                                        *
*******************************************************************************/
template<class RandomIt, class Cmp>
void natural_merge_sort(RandomIt first, RandomIt last, Cmp cmp)
{
    const size_t length = std::distance(first, last);

    if (length < 2)
    {
        // Trivially sorted.
        return;
    }

    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<RandomIt>::value_type value_type;
    RandomIt buffer = new value_type[length];
    natural_merge_sort_impl(first, last, buffer, cmp);
    delete[] buffer;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Implements parallel merge sort.                                              *
*******************************************************************************/
template<class RandomIt, class Cmp>
void parallel_natural_merge_sort_impl(RandomIt source, 
                                      RandomIt target, 
                                      const size_t length, 
                                      const size_t thread_quota,
                                      Cmp cmp)
{
    if (thread_quota == 1)
    {
        natural_merge_sort_impl(target, target + length, source, cmp);
        return;
    }

    const size_t left_quota = thread_quota / 2;
    const size_t right_quota = thread_quota - left_quota;
    const size_t left_length = length / 2;

    if (thread_quota == 2)
    {
        std::thread thread_(natural_merge_sort_impl<RandomIt, Cmp>,
                            source,
                            source + left_length,
                            target,
                            cmp);

        natural_merge_sort_impl(source + left_length, 
                                source + length, 
                                target + left_length, 
                                cmp);

        thread_.join();

        std::merge(source, 
                   source + left_length, 
                   source + left_length, 
                   source + length,
                   target,
                   cmp);
        return;
    }

    std::thread left_thread(parallel_natural_merge_sort_impl<RandomIt, Cmp>,
                            target, 
                            source, 
                            left_length, 
                            left_quota, 
                            cmp);

    parallel_natural_merge_sort_impl(target + left_length, 
                                     source + left_length, 
                                     length - left_length, 
                                     right_quota, 
                                     cmp);
    // Wait for the left thread.
    left_thread.join();

    // Merge the two chunks.
    std::merge(source, 
               source + left_length, 
               source + left_length, 
               source + length,
               target,
               cmp);
}

/*******************************************************************************
* The actual parallel merge sort. If the system has N CPU cores, this sort     *     
* will split the range into N chunks of equal length assuming that N is a      *
* power of two, sort them concurrently and merge.                              *
*******************************************************************************/
template<class RandomIt, class Cmp>
void parallel_natural_merge_sort(RandomIt begin, RandomIt end, Cmp cmp)
{
    // At least 16384 elements per thread.
    constexpr size_t MINIMUM_THREAD_LOAD = 1 << 14;
    const size_t cores = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
    const size_t length = std::distance(begin, end);
    const size_t spawn = std::min(cores, length / MINIMUM_THREAD_LOAD);

    if (spawn < 2)
    {
        natural_merge_sort(begin, end, cmp);
        return;
    }

    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<RandomIt>::value_type value_type;
    RandomIt buffer = new value_type[length];
    std::copy(begin, end, buffer);
    parallel_natural_merge_sort_impl(buffer, begin, length, spawn, cmp);
}

#endif
```

**main.cpp**:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

#include "parallel_natural_merge_sort.h"

/*******************************************************************************
* Creates a random integer array of length 'length', minimum integer           *
* 'minimum', maximum integer 'maximum', using seed 'seed'.                     *
*******************************************************************************/
static int* get_random_int_array(const size_t length,
                                 const int minimum,
                                 const int maximum,
                                 const unsigned int seed)
{
    std::default_random_engine generator(seed);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(minimum, maximum);

    int* array = new int[length];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        array[i] = distribution(generator);
    }

    return array;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Create an array of pointers to integers.                                     *
*******************************************************************************/
static int** get_random_int_pointer_array(const size_t length,
                                          const int minimum,
                                          const int maximum,
                                          const unsigned seed)
{
    std::default_random_engine generator(seed);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(minimum, maximum);

    int** array = new int*[length];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        array[i] = new int(distribution(generator));
    }

    return array;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Returns a strongly presorted array of integers.                              *
*******************************************************************************/
static int* get_presorted_int_array(const size_t length)
{
    int* array = new int[length];
    int num = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < length / 2; ++i)
    {
        array[i] = num++;
    }

    for (size_t i = length / 2; i < length; ++i)
    {
        array[i] = num--;
    }

    return array;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Returns the milliseconds since the Unix epoch.                               *
*******************************************************************************/
static unsigned long long get_milliseconds()
{
    return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(
           std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Profiles the 'std::stable_sort' agains the range ['begin', 'end') using the  *
* comparator 'cmp'.                                                            *
*******************************************************************************/
template<class T, class Cmp>
static void profile_stable_sort(T begin, T end, Cmp cmp)
{
    unsigned long long ta = get_milliseconds();
    std::stable_sort(begin, end, cmp);
    unsigned long long tb = get_milliseconds();

    std::cout << "std::stable_sort in "
              << (tb - ta)
              << " milliseconds. "
              << "Sorted: "
              << std::is_sorted(begin, end, cmp)
              << std::endl;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Profiles the 'natural_merge_sort' agains the range ['begin', 'end') using    *
* the comparator 'cmp'.                                                        *
*******************************************************************************/
template<class T, class Cmp>
void profile_natural_merge_sort(T begin, T end, Cmp cmp)
{
    unsigned long long ta = get_milliseconds();
    natural_merge_sort(begin, end, cmp);
    unsigned long long tb = get_milliseconds();

    std::cout << "natural_merge_sort in "
              << (tb - ta)
              << " milliseconds. "
              << "Sorted: "
              << std::is_sorted(begin, end, cmp)
              << std::endl;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Profiles the 'natural_merge_sort' agains the range ['begin', 'end') using    *
* the comparator 'cmp'.                                                        *
*******************************************************************************/
template<class T, class Cmp>
void profile_parallel_natural_merge_sort(T begin, T end, Cmp cmp)
{
    unsigned long long ta = get_milliseconds();
    parallel_natural_merge_sort(begin, end, cmp);
    unsigned long long tb = get_milliseconds();

    std::cout << "parallel_natural_merge_sort in "
              << (tb - ta)
              << " milliseconds. "
              << "Sorted: "
              << std::is_sorted(begin, end, cmp)
              << std::endl;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Profiles the sorting algorithms on a random integer array.                   *
*******************************************************************************/
static void profile_on_random_array(const size_t sz,
                                    const int minimum,
                                    const int maximum,
                                    const unsigned seed)
{
    int* array1 = get_random_int_array(sz, minimum, maximum, seed);
    int* array2 = new int[sz];
    int* array3 = new int[sz];

    std::copy(array1, array1 + sz, array2);
    std::copy(array1, array1 + sz, array3);

    std::cout << "--- PROFILING ON RANDOM ARRAY OF LENGTH "
              << sz
              << " ---"
              << std::endl;

    profile_stable_sort(array1, 
                        array1 + sz, 
                        std::less<>());

    profile_natural_merge_sort(array2, 
                               array2 + sz, 
                               std::less<>());

    profile_parallel_natural_merge_sort(array3,
                                        array3 + sz,
                                        std::less<>());

    std::cout << "Same contents: "
              << (std::equal(array1, array1 + sz, array2, array2 + sz)
                 && std::equal(array1, array1 + sz, array3, array3 + sz))
              << std::endl
              << std::endl;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Profiles the sorting algorithms on an array of pointers to random integers.  *
*******************************************************************************/
static void profile_on_integer_pointer_array(const size_t sz,
                                             const int minimum,
                                             const int maximum,
                                             const unsigned seed)
{
    std::cout << "--- PROFILING ON RANDOM POINTER ARRAY OF LENGTH "
              << sz
              << " ---"
              << std::endl;

    int** array1 = get_random_int_pointer_array(sz,
                                                minimum,
                                                maximum,
                                                seed);
    int** array2 = new int*[sz];
    int** array3 = new int*[sz];

    std::copy(array1, array1 + sz, array2);
    std::copy(array1, array1 + sz, array3);

    auto lambda = [](int* a, int* b){
        return *a < *b;
    };

    profile_stable_sort(array1, 
                        array1 + sz, 
                        lambda);

    profile_natural_merge_sort(array2, 
                               array2 + sz, 
                               lambda);

    profile_parallel_natural_merge_sort(array3,
                                        array3 + sz,
                                        lambda);
    std::cout << "Same contents: "
              << (std::equal(array1, array1 + sz, array2, array2 + sz)
                 && std::equal(array1, array1 + sz, array3, array3 + sz))
              << std::endl
              << std::endl;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Profiles the sorting algorithms on a presorted array.                        *
*******************************************************************************/
static void profile_on_presorted_array(const size_t sz)
{
    std::cout << "--- PROFILING ON PRESORTED ARRAY OF LENGTH "
              << sz
              << " ---"
              << std::endl;

    int* array1 = get_presorted_int_array(sz);
    int* array2 = new int[sz];
    int* array3 = new int[sz];

    std::copy(array1, array1 + sz, array2);
    std::copy(array1, array1 + sz, array3);

    profile_stable_sort(array1, 
                        array1 + sz, 
                        std::less<>());

    profile_natural_merge_sort(array2, 
                               array2 + sz, 
                               std::less<>());

    profile_parallel_natural_merge_sort(array3,
                                        array3 + sz,
                                        std::less<>());

    std::cout << "Same contents: "
              << (std::equal(array1, array1 + sz, array2, array2 + sz) 
                 && std::equal(array1, array1 + sz, array3, array3 + sz))
              << std::endl
              << std::endl;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* The entry point to a demo program.                                           *
*******************************************************************************/
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    unsigned long long seed = get_milliseconds();

    std::cout << "Seed: "
              << seed
              << std::endl
              << std::endl;

    const size_t length = 5000000;
    const int min_int = -100;
    const int max_int = 300;

    std::cout << std::boolalpha;

    profile_on_random_array(length, min_int, max_int, seed);
    profile_on_integer_pointer_array(length, min_int, max_int, seed);
    profile_on_presorted_array(length);

    return 0;
}
```

Is there room for improvement? Efficiency? Style? Naming?

Comment: My computer is dual-core. Can anybody with more than two cores report on performace of the parallel sort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The style looks pretty idiomatic to me. Comments:

---

```
UnsafeIntQueue* p_q = new UnsafeIntQueue(length / 2 + 1);
... cmp(*right, *left) ...
return std::unique_ptr<UnsafeIntQueue>(p_q);
```

If the user-provided comparator `cmp` throws an exception, you leak memory. Prefer to wrap the heap-allocated object in a `unique_ptr` right away, so that if an exception is thrown it will be destroyed properly.

```
auto p_q = std::make_unique<UnsafeIntQueue>(length / 2 + 1);
... cmp(*right, *left) ...
return p_q;
```

---

In fact, `build_run_size_queue` should simply return a value of type `UnsafeIntQueue` — you don't need to muck around with heap-allocation here at all. Get rid of the `unique_ptr` and just return a simple `UnsafeIntQueue` directly.

---

Which brings up the fact that `UnsafeIntQueue` is not safe for copying or moving. (That's probably why you wrapped it in a `unique_ptr`: because you couldn't get it to work as a value type.) The solution to *that* is to get rid of *that* manual memory management; replace `size_t *m_buffer` with `std::vector<size_t> m_buffer`, and replace all uses of `m_mask` with `m_buffer.size()`. Don't worry about a loss of efficiency: `std::vector` works exactly like a `new`'ed array under the hood, as long as you stick to indexing with `m_buffer[i]` instead of `m_buffer.at(i)`.

---

```
size_t leading_zeros(const size_t num)
{
    size_t count = 0;

    for (size_t t = (size_t) 1 << (8 * sizeof(t) - 1); t; t >>= 1, ++count)
    {
        if ((t & num))
        {
            return count;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

I would write this as

```
// Use __builtin_clzll(x) if available; otherwise...
size_t clz(size_t x)
{
    size_t result = CHAR_BIT * sizeof(x);
    while (x != 0) {
        x >>= 1;
        result -= 1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Four lines shorter, including the comment (although it will get longer if you actually add the `#ifdef`s to use the non-standard compiler builtin). The main savings is due to brace style. Putting in the explicit `!= 0` is a good habit because it will silence warnings from some compilers. (Some compilers these days have blacklisted "assignment-used-as-an-expression" to such an extent that they actually warn about `if ((expr))` — you put two pairs of parentheses where only one was needed, so clearly you've made some kind of mistake!)

Parameters and return values in C++11-or-later should *never* be const-qualified; it inhibits move semantics in general, and is thus a bad habit that you should break ASAP.

Note that `std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::digits` is a valid synonym for `CHAR_BIT`, and in fact so is `8` in my opinion; but then in my opinion `64` is a valid synonym for `8 * sizeof(x)`, and you're clearly not willing to make *that* assumption yet.

---

In `parallel_natural_merge_sort`:

```
RandomIt buffer = new value_type[length];
```

This doesn't even compile, unless `RandomIt` happens to be `value_type*`. Try it with `std::vector<value_type>::iterator` or the like, and see what happens.

Furthermore, if it *does* compile, you get a memory leak because nobody ever frees the `new`'ed buffer. Replace your manual memory management with `std::vector<value_type> buffer(length);`, and change `parallel_natural_merge_sort_impl` to take *two* template type parameters `RandomIt1` and `RandomIt2`, which are not necessarily synonymous.

---

Being able to call `new value_type[length]` (or `std::vector<value_type>(length)`) depends on `value_type` being default-constructible, which might not be the case: it might be moveable but not default-constructible nor even copyable. Does the "natural merge sort" algorithm really *require* that the type be copyable, or could you refactor this code to work with moves alone?

---

```
/* Scans the range [first, last) ... */
```

The usual names in C++ for the endpoints of a half-open range are `begin` and `end`. I don't see a good reason not to use those names here. This would free up the name `last` (or, idiomatically, `back`) for the pointer-to-last-item variable which is currently confusingly named `lst`.

---

```
const size_t length = std::distance(first, last);
```

The actual return type here is `std::iterator_traits<RandomIt>::difference_type`, which is most likely signed `ptrdiff_t` but could be anything under the sun (and is not necessarily convertible to `size_t`). This is a great place to use `auto` to make your code more generic. I haven't traced all the way down the rabbit hole, but I'm pretty sure that ultimately you'll want to make `UnsafeIntQueue` into a class template so that it can store `difference_type`s instead of merely `size_t`s.

---

Inside `natural_merge_sort_impl`:

```
typedef typename std::iterator_traits<RandomIt>::value_type value_type;
```

This is scrupulously correct, but (A) in C++11-and-later it's idiomatic to use the new syntax

```
using value_type = std::iterator_traits<RandomIt>::value_type;
```

and (B) you don't actually use this typedef anywhere in the function.

---

In `parallel_natural_merge_sort_impl`:

```
if (thread_quota == 2)
```

You can kill this whole block, can't you? The code immediately below the `if` block appears to do exactly the same thing (spawn two threads, join them, merge the resulting arrays).

---

In `build_run_size_queue`, if it's permitted by the rules of the game, consider simply invoking `std::sort` on the buffer (or maybe on medium-sized chunks of it). Right now you're wasting a lot of time comparing elements in order to come up with run-lengths that will generally be only `2` or `3`, and then you're going to waste time *again* comparing those elements to each other in order to merge them. You could instead do something like "Count up the run-length starting at `p`; if you find that the run-length is less than 100, then `std::sort` the 100 elements starting at `p` and then continue counting from `p+100`" (with suitable bounds-checking, of course).

---

As usual, no comment on the correctness of the algorithm. However, I find it hard to believe that any sort algorithm with so many `std::copy`s on large ranges could outperform an algorithm that uses only `move` and `swap`.

Comment: `std::numeric_limits<T>::digits` is a synonym for `CHAR_BIT * sizeof(T)` too, and is almost as short. That's what I would use in the relevant part of the code :)